# query modification without using Analytical function

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone please help me modify this below code with using analytical/aggregate function aas i have to use it creating a **materialized view** with **fast on commit** refresh option.

```
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT table_A.column3, table_b.column4,
            CASE  WHEN table_b.col5 = 'A' THEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY table_A.col1, table_b.col5 ORDER BY table_b.col6, table_b.col7 DESC) END AS rnk_a,
            CASE WHEN table_b.col5 = 'Z' THEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY table_A.col1, table_b.col5 ORDER BY table_b.col6 DESC, table_b.col7 DESC) END AS rnk_z
        FROM table_A
        INNER JOIN table_B sc ON tale_B.col4 = table_a.col3
    )
WHERE (RNK_A = 1) OR (RNK_Z = 1)

*sample dataset:*

 id     col5    col6   col7
A1A150    A      001    20245
A1A150    A      002    20246
A1A150    A      002    20244
A1A150    Z      001    1023
A1A150    Z      002    1022

Expected resultset:

  id     col5     col6   col7
A1A150    A       002    20246
A1A150    Z       001    1023
```

**If multiple records for col5 = 'A' or col5 = 'Z'  found then:  take min(col6) and max(col7)

when multiple records with loc = 'A' or loc = 'Z' with same col5 and diff col7 value is found, the max logic is not working. please correct me where i'm going wrong.

```
SELECT col1, col2  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT table_A.column3, table_b.column4,
          CASE WHEN table_b.col5 = 'A' AND table_b.col7 = (SELECT MAX(table_b.col7) FROM table_b cp1 WHERE cp1.id = table_A.col1 GROUP BY table_A.col1)THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS rnk_a,
          CASE WHEN table_b.col5 = 'Z' AND table_b.col7 = (SELECT MAX(table_b.col7) FROM table_b cp1 WHERE cp1.id = table_A.col1 GROUP BY table_A.col1)THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS rnk_z
        FROM table_A
        INNER JOIN table_B sc ON tale_B.col4 = table_a.col3
    )
WHERE (RNK_A = 1) OR (RNK_Z = 1)
```

Comment: it does not seem to be real min/max as col7 is always in descending order?

Comment: so i'm computing to get loc = A and loc = b,
`to get loc = 'A'- take min of table_b.col6 and max of table_b.col7
``to get loc = 'Z' take max of table_b.col6 and table_b.max col7

`col6 and col7 hold numberic value (eg: value of col6 001, 002, 003 and col7: has data like 4321, 4320, 4319.)

Comment: The better option is to post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: @iminiki, Please add the sample data and expected result.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai this is not my question!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using sub query -

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.col5, T1.col6, T1.col7
FROM table_A T1
JOIN (SELECT id, col5, MAX(col7) col7
      FROM table_B
      GROUP BY id, col5) T2
ON T1.id = T2.id 
AND T1.col5 = T2.col5
AND T1.col7 = T2.col7
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. i did try your logic but its not pulling the max(col7) when multiple records with loc = 'A' and col5 is same for both the record.

Comment: Can you add this sample data in the question? I guess this query is working fine for other test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` and `ROW_NUMBER()` to rank the records in a subquery (or `RANK()`, if that better fits your use case), and then filter in the outer query:

```
SELECT id, col5, col6, col7
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        CASE col5
            WHEN 'A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col5 ORDER BY col6 DESC, col7 DESC)
            WHEN 'Z' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col5 ORDER BY col6 ASC,  col7 DESC)
        END rn
    FROM mytable t
) x 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: @GMB- Thanks for the response. the code i shared work as expected. But Fast on Commit on materialized view has some restriction so i cannot use analyical function, rank() / row_number (). hence neeed some help converting my code shared.